# convert numberformat (coldfusion)

Tags: coldfusion, number-formatting, decimal

HI folks! i got a simple question for coldfusion users, does anyone know how to convert a dynamic number into decimals, for example i have a code: #number# and it equals to, for example 10 but i need to write it as 0.10 how do i do it? 
tried this: 0.#number# didnt work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So are you saying that your values in the variable "number" will have 2 decimal places at the end and that you need to display those decimal places?

If so :

```
<cfset actualNumber = incomingNumber/10>
<cfoutput>#NumberFormat(actualNumber,".00")#</cfoutput>
```

should do what you need.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `NumberFormat` has a ton of mask options, explained in manual http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_m-r_08.html#134113

Comment: also worth mentioning is decimalFormat which will automatically format it to 2 decimal points (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d58.html)